# Do I add my Strength modifier to the damage of unarmed strikes if I have the Tavern Brawler feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, damage, unarmed-combat

Do I add my Strength modifier to the damage of unarmed strikes if I have the Tavern Brawler feat?

From my understanding, the attack roll would be 1d20 + Proficiency + Str modifier. My question is about the damage roll. Would that be 1d4 + Str modifier, or just 1d4?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Absolutely

The SRD states clearly (whether you are a Tavern Brawler or not) that:

> ...you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons). On a hit, an unarmed strike deals ***bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your Strength modifier.***

(emphasis mine)

And when you take the Tavern Brawler feat:

> Your unarmed strikes use a d4 for damage.

That means the "1" in the above formula (the base damage) changes to 1d4 -- it does not say that it takes away the Strength modifier, so you still keep that modifier.

Comment: Could you explain why the d4 replaces just the "1" and not "1 + your Strength modifier"?  I don't see where you're getting that from.

Comment: The [Sage Advice Compendium's answer to "How do I know which ability modifier to use with an attack roll and its damage roll?"](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=10) indicates that the ability modifier is added to both attack and damage rolls of all "melee weapon attacks" (which unarmed strikes are). [Crawford also unofficially tweeted in May 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/727575357868539905): "When making a weapon attack, you add your ability modifier to the damage, unless a feature tells you not to.", further supporting your conclusion.